# Python - how to split by blank space if string element itself contains space?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file with lines:

```
/home/Plugins/file1 e:222 k:dir (327/1)
/home/Plugins/file2 e:100 k:dir (326/1)
```

I want to take a path and element id.
That's easy.

```
with open('output_file.txt', 'r') as output_file:
    for line in output_file:
        file_path = line.split()[0]
        eId = line.split()[1].split(":")[1]
        logging.info("file path:"+file_path)
        logging.info("eId:"+eId)
```

But, the problem is that this Path of the file name (first element) itself can contain spaces - as **folders** OR **files** on the disk are created with blank space in their name (which is common case).
So, I have these examples:

```
/home/tools/AMS Provider/file3.txt e:224 k:dir (127/1)
/home/account validator e:227 k:dir (247/1)
```

So path is always the first element but sometimes it contains spaces. My script above will fail because of these examples.
*In the given example:*

AMS Provider **(subfolder name)**

account validator **(file name at the end of the path)**

Since, in this case, paths contain blank spaces (in the subfolder name but also in the file name at the end of the path) how I can still retrieve the path of the file.
How to split it?

**Note:** unfortunately I am limited with python **2.7** on the server.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use regex:

```py
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(.*) (e:\d*) (k:.*) \((\d{3}/\d)\)$"

test_str = ("/home/Plugins/file1 e:222 k:dir (327/1)\n"
            "/home/Plugins/file2 e:100 k:dir (326/1)\n"
            "/home/tools/AMS Provider/file3.txt e:224 k:dir (127/1)\n"
            "/home/account validator e:227 k:dir (247/1)")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".
           format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(),
                  end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".
               format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum),
                      end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex
#       and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Output:

```
Match 1 was found at 0-39: /home/Plugins/file1 e:222 k:dir (327/1)
Group 1 found at 0-19: /home/Plugins/file1
Group 2 found at 20-25: e:222
Group 3 found at 26-31: k:dir
Group 4 found at 33-38: 327/1
Match 2 was found at 40-79: /home/Plugins/file2 e:100 k:dir (326/1)
Group 1 found at 40-59: /home/Plugins/file2
Group 2 found at 60-65: e:100
Group 3 found at 66-71: k:dir
Group 4 found at 73-78: 326/1
Match 3 was found at 80-134: /home/tools/AMS Provider/file3.txt e:224 k:dir (127/1)
Group 1 found at 80-114: /home/tools/AMS Provider/file3.txt
Group 2 found at 115-120: e:224
Group 3 found at 121-126: k:dir
Group 4 found at 128-133: 127/1
Match 4 was found at 135-178: /home/account validator e:227 k:dir (247/1)
Group 1 found at 135-158: /home/account validator
Group 2 found at 159-164: e:227
Group 3 found at 165-170: k:dir
Group 4 found at 172-177: 247/1
```

[Playground](https://regex101.com/r/TjRnxM/1).

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3:

```
txt = "/home/tools/AMS Provider/file3.txt e:224 k:dir (127/1)"

x = txt.rsplit(" ", 3)

print(x[0])
```

Result: `/home/tools/AMS Provider/file3.txt`

In Python 2:

```
txt_list = ["/home/tools/AMS Provider/file3.txt e:224 k:dir (127/1)", "/home/account validator e:227 k:dir (247/1)"]

for x in txt_list:
    result = x.rsplit(" ", 3)
    print result[0]
```

Result:

```
/home/tools/AMS Provider/file3.txt
/home/account validator
```

Comment: what about if input is like this? /home/tools/AMS Provider/file3.txt e:224 k:dir (127/1)
/home/account validator e:227 k:dir (247/1)

Comment: does it work for `/home/account validator` case as well?

Comment: I does work for any scenario where path has one or more spaces, and the result is in format `e:227 k:dir (247/1)` . This should probably be the accepted answer, in a reasonably perfect world. This however isn't one, so... nvm. Hope it helped.

Comment: Simple, with minimal assumptions on the format of the text, just the number of elements. But why distinguish Python 3 and Python 2? It's the same for both, right?

Comment: Because I didn't write Python 2 in ages, and I wasn't sure - had to doublecheck - and for the benefit of others using Python 3 (q was for Python 2). The difference is in `print` statement.

Comment: Ah, right. But the `print` is not really relevant, and you could do `print(...)` in Python 2, too (without extra parameters, the `(...)` is just ignored). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since your filePath will contain `e:` as element id.
In that case we can split using this info. Just like the following.

```py
paths = ['/home/tools/AMS Provider/file3.txt e:224 k:dir (127/1)',
'/home/account validator e:227 k:dir (247/1)', '/home/Plugins/file1 e:222 k:dir (327/1)',
'/home/Plugins/file2 e:100 k:dir (326/1)'];

for path in paths:
    [filePath, id] = path.split(' e:')
    id = id.split(' ')[0]
    filePath = filePath.strip()
    print([filePath, id])
```

Comment: welcome, please let all know if it helps 